Oracle: Using RAW or BLOB for a variable-length but small byte array
I have a column in a table that is populated with a byte array. The size of this byte array is variable and can range from 20 to 200 bytes. This table can have billions of records, so if its value for a record is only 20 bytes, only 20 bytes of storage should be consumed (nothing should be reserved) Which one is more suitable for this requirement, RAW or BLOB?

BLOBs impose severe processing penalties, so are definitely not recommended since your max size is well below 2KB.
RAW is variable length, so would be the most efficient space-wise, storing only what you need without overhead.
You also have the option of a VARRAY(10) OF RAW(20) which works naturally with arrays. It would cost 7 bytes overhead for the full array plus one length byte for each array element, so anywhere from 9 bytes to 227 to store your variable array data up to the 200 bytes.
create type test_varray_type is varray(10) of raw(20)
create table test1 (test_raw raw(200), test_varray test_varray_type);
insert into test1 values (HEXTORAW('ABACAD'),test_varray_type(HEXTORAW('AB'),HEXTORAW('AC'),HEXTORAW('AD')));

Block dump shows 3 bytes for the raw and 13 bytes for the varray. So more overhead penalty at very small values, but the difference diminishes with larger values.

So, can I define the column with the maximum length (raw(2000)) without worrying about wasting storage?

@Arya, That's correct, however, if your maximum value is 200, you should declare that by using raw(200), not raw(2000). Overstating your real maximum by an excessive amount can lead to various inefficiencies in certain clients, not to mention fail to be self-documenting.
